# How to fix "Table containes irregular row lengths" in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting **Table contains irregular row length** error when i'm trying to display table from **html** using **flutter_html: 1.0.0** plugin. how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

A new version of flutter_html has been published. It seems to be solved. I tried it out.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/install
flutter_html: ^1.2.0